# VSCode Codespaces - cut off letters in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, fonts

I used VSCode Codespaces for the first time today and everything works as in the desktop version but somehow the letters in the terminal are cut off and i don't know how to change it. I tried few font settings, cleared the JSON settings file but still the same. I saw same problem in few forums but didn't find a solution.
[this is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oS6J.png)

Comment: Did you try the terminal letter spacing setting?

Comment: There was actually a terminal spacing option, must have overlooked it. I set it to 2 and the letters look good again. Thank you :)